# current_page? method causes error 500 when used with rails_admin and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I try to use current_page? method in my navbar this way:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
      <li class="<%="active" if current_page?(controller: :welcome)%>"><%= link_to "Home", "/"%></li>
      <li class="<%="active" if current_page?(controller: :products)%>"><%= link_to "Store", "/products"%></li>
      <li class="<%="active" if current_page?(controller: :catalog)%>"><%= link_to "Catalog", "/catalog"%></li>
...
```

Everything works fine when I move between pages.
But when I try to go to `/admin` which is provided by rails_admin I get 500 internal server  error in response. This is probably caused by current_page? method because if I remove them from layout everything works fine.

I'll appreciate any solution.

Comment: What is error backtrace?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to see full error backtrace, but my console says "rendered 500 internal server error" in the end

Comment: Is there anything else in the console output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just disabled using default layout by adding `layout false` in devise session controller and everything works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone runs into this and wants to fix it, you need to use absolute urls in the way you pass parameters to current_page?

So in your case, this code will work:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
  <li class="<%="active" if current_page?(controller: '/welcome')%>"><%= link_to "Home", "/"%></li>
  <li class="<%="active" if current_page?(controller: '/products')%>"><%= link_to "Store", "/products"%></li>
  <li class="<%="active" if current_page?(controller: '/catalog'')%>"><%= link_to "Catalog", "/catalog"%></li>
```